# How can I make a wedding toast in Spanish (1 sentence)?

Tags: traducción

!Hola! I'm going to make a wedding speech for the groom next week in Spain. I will give the speech in English, but I'd like to end it with the Spanish quote (bride is Spanish). Any suggestion on the one sentence wedding toast in Spanish?

Thanks in advance :)

P.S. I've asked reddit for help, but I only got the inappropriate ones (some quite funny though)

Comment: what you want to say to her? you need some tipical phrase for this context? like *¡viva los novios!*, you want to express some feeling to the couple in spanish, or some joke like *Aunque os lo habéis buscado, os deseo toda la felicidad* ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best sentence you can use is *¡Vivan los novios!* It is short, easy and very, very usual in a wedding, so everybody will understand it even if your pronunciation is not so good. You cannot go wrong with that.